# youtube api v3 channel methods not working

Tags: php, youtube-data-api

there was a question about the YouTube api, regarding information about channels, some channels are not displayed by name, for example HajimeRecords and GUZNO and kuplinovplay, the latter only outputs all the information.
What can this problem be related to?
Requesting everything regarding the channels method
My request https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?forUsername=GUZNO&key=*****&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go I hope:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=id%2Csnippet&q={channel name}&type=channel&key={API KEY}
```

Explanation as I understand:

youtube.com/c/{CHANNEL_NAME}
is not the same as
youtube.com/channel/{CHANNEL ID}

Youtube V3 wants you to use Channel ID for all requests.  That GET will provide you with what you want AFIK using the Channel name `/c/THIS`.